# sorting rows when exporting pandas csv file

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a CSV file that contains 700k rows and what I need to do is create an additional CSV that has taken the data I need and sorted it into order.

So for example my original csv file has data that looks a bit like this.

```
Name     Code   Date        Area
Peter     01    01/01/2016  Wales
Peter     02    01/02/2017  England
Peter     34    25/02/2018  Wales
Paul      65    01/12/2015  Scotland
Paul      12    02/12/2015  Scotland
Simon     12    23/08/2016  England
Simon     12    28/09/2016  Wales
Simon     12    27/10/2018  England
```

What I need to do is create a unique row for a person but list the codes based on when the code was made (oldest date first). I should point out that I sorted the dataset in Excel to list the dates in the correct order (oldest first) to see if that would help.

So the output I need should look like this:

```
Name   Codes   
Peter  01,02,34
Paul   65,12
Simon  12,12,12
```

The codes are listed in order by oldest date.

I'm not interested in the Area as it has no relevance to final answer.

I have successfully managed to get the names and codes into the relevant columns but for some reason the codes are not listed by oldest date.

I have tried searching for this but can't seem to word it correctly to get a relevant result.

Does anyone know why the sequence does not export correctly?

The code I am using is:

```
df2 = df2.groupby ('Name')['Code'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
df2
export_csv = df2.to_csv(r'Filelocation.csv', index = None, header = True)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following might work:

```
df2.groupby('Name')['Code'].apply(lambda x: " " % ', '.join(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not aware of what `df2` holds for you, so I created a dataframe and verified your code which gives me the correct sequence. Implement and let me know what doesn't work for you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Paul', 'Paul', 'Simon', 'Simon', 'Simon'],
                   'Code': ['01', '02', '34', '65', '12', '12', '12', '12']})
df

    Code    Name
0   01  Peter
1   02  Peter
2   34  Peter
3   65  Paul
4   12  Paul
5   12  Simon
6   12  Simon
7   12  Simon

dfn = df.groupby ('Name')['Code'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
dfn

    Name    Code
0   Paul    65, 12
1   Peter   01, 02, 34
2   Simon   12, 12, 12

dfn.index = dfn.Name # Mapping index with column Name
dfn.drop(columns=['Name'], inplace=True) # Dropping column Name
dfn

        Code
Name    
Paul    65, 12
Peter   01, 02, 34
Simon   12, 12, 12

dfn = dfn.loc[df.Name.unique()] # Bringing dataframe into your desired order
dfn

        Code
Name    
Peter   01, 02, 34
Paul    65, 12
Simon   12, 12, 12


dfn.to_csv('sample.csv')
```

[image: img]

Is this what you need? If not, comment.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. a 'ValueError' has risen cannot index with vector containing NA/NaN values.

Comment: Can you clarify your original dataframe by modifying your question. I cannot help in the mid of your question.

Comment: Of course - I have a csv file that contains 700k rows that has many columns but there are only 3 I am interested in, these being 'Name', 'Code' and 'Date'. I have created a dataframe based on these and called it df2. All I need to do is create unique rows by 'Name' and then list the codes based on the Date they were made, as in the output you provided. I originally sorted the CSV file by date to see if that helped in the sort but it didn't. Perhaps if I sort by date through Python would help? Thanks

Comment: @MartinPugsley Can you modify your dataframe in question along with a date column and then showcase a final expected output. If you can do that, it'll be quite easy to answer.

Comment: I have edited my original post to see if that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely you didn't specify `dayfirst=True` when converting your series to `datetime`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

You can then sort by `Date` and perform a `groupby` operation as normal:

```
res = df.sort_values('Date')\
        .groupby('Name')['Code']\
        .agg(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
```